# Fleck - send data from server

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

We have today an event based application centered completely on desktop.  We want to move to web and drive events using Web Sockets using Fleck.  I was unable to figure out how to send message asynchronously from server to client in fleck.  Below is the sample for what I am trying to achieve

```
public class Program
{
    static readonly WebSocketServer _webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer("ws://127.0.0.1:8181");
    static readonly List<IWebSocketConnection> SocketClients = new List<IWebSocketConnection>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _webSocketServer.Start(socket =>
        {
            socket.OnOpen = () =>
            {
                SocketClients.Add(socket);
                OnOpening(socket.ConnectionInfo.Id);
            };

            socket.OnClose = () =>
            {
                OnClosing(socket.ConnectionInfo.Id);
                SocketClients.Remove(socket);
            };

            socket.OnMessage = message => OnMessage(message, socket.ConnectionInfo.Id);
        });
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void OnMessage(string message, Guid id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("<i> Recived message " + message + " from Client Id : " + id + " </i>");
    }


    private static void OnClosing(Guid id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("<i> Client Left With Id : " + id + "</i>");
    }

    private static void OnOpening(Guid id)
    {
        //Do Something

    }

    // CALL THIS METHOD FROM MY APPLICATION AND SEND THE MESSAGE TO CLIENT BASED ON THE ID
    private static void SendMessage(string message, Guid id)
    {
        // HOW TO DO SOMETHING LIKE BELOW SEND MESSAGE ASYNC 
        //_webSocketServer.Start(socket =>
        //{
        //    var clientToSend = SocketClients.Find(client => client.ConnectionInfo.Id == id);
        //    socket.Send(message);
        //});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a similar example in their GitHub: https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck/blob/master/src/Samples/ConsoleApp/Server.cs

I just added the `SendToSocketById` method>

```
class Server
{
    static void Main()
    {
        FleckLog.Level = LogLevel.Debug;
        var allSockets = new List<IWebSocketConnection>();
        var server = new WebSocketServer("ws://0.0.0.0:8181");
        server.Start(socket =>
            {
                socket.OnOpen = () =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Open!");
                        allSockets.Add(socket);
                    };
                socket.OnClose = () =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Close!");
                        allSockets.Remove(socket);
                    };
                socket.OnMessage = message =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(message);
                        allSockets.ToList().ForEach(s => s.Send("Echo: " + message));
                    };
            });


        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        while (input != "exit")
        {
            foreach (var socket in allSockets.ToList())
            {
                socket.Send(input);
            }
            input = Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

    static void SendToSocketById(String input, Guid id)
    {
         var socket = allSockets.Find(client => client.ConnectionInfo.Id == id);
         socket.Send(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: How will the Program get the Guid of the socket? to call SendToSocketById?